# Big-Theta Complexity of Recursive Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am currently trying to determine the *Big-Theta* complexity of the recursive algorithm below. It makes sense that the complexity is at least n^2 (due to the nested for-loop). However, the recursive aspect makes me struggle to determine its precise Big-Theta complexity.

I guess it must be n^3 as the function calls itself recursively and executes itself. But I struggle to find proof for that. Can anyone please tell me the complexity and how to determine it for recursive algorithms?

```
function F(n)
    if n < 1: 
        return 1
    t = 0
    for i <- 0 to n:
        for j <- i to n:
            t = t + j
    return t + F(n-1)
```

Comment: It should be `O(n^3)` due to recursion and nested looping used in the recursive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion aspect of this algorithm is fairly simple: it comes down to [*tail recursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and so it can be written as a loop:

```py
function F(n)
    t = 0
    for k <- n to 1:
        for i <- 0 to k:
            for j <- i to k:
                t = t + j
    return t + 1
```

...where `k` replaces the argument that each recursive call would get as `n`

The number of times that `t = t + j` executes is determining for the time complexity (assuming addition is considered a Θ(1) step).

This represents a [tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) and is Θ(n³).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Just one follow-up: Does that mean the algorithm's complexity is also in Big-Theta of n^3? Or just Big-Oh of (n^3)?

Comment: As there is no other input variable than *n* here, there is no variation in the number of iterations. It is only determined by the value of *n*. That means there is no worst or best case, just one case, and so it is Big Theta.